# Adding mass to a bowl until it sinks

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, buoyancy, statics

I've been struggling with this question.

A hemispherical bowl of inner radius $r$, density $ϕ$ and thickness $t$ is floating in a fluid of density $ρ$. The bowl is being filled with sand at a constant mass-rate $α$. What is the length of time $T$ before the bowl sinks below the surface?

The bowl is in equilibrium, I drew a diagram of the bowl and all the forces acting on it. Using Archimedes' principle, there must be a buoyancy force acting on the bowl equal to the weight of the volume of water the bowl displaces. With the information  given in the question, the volume of water displaced if the bowl were completely solid (not hollow) would be $\frac{2}{3}π(r+t)^3ρ$. The volume displaced by the "outer ring" of the bowl, i.e. the non-hollow part, would be $\frac{2}{3}πr^2tϕ$. Therefore, the total volume of water displaced by the bowl would be the difference between these, i.e. $\frac{2}{3}π(r+t)^3ρ - \frac{2}{3}πr^2tϕ$. I think that the bowl would sink when the weight of the sand is greater than this buoyancy force, and therefore the length of time, $T$, should be the volume displaced divided by $α$, so $\frac{2}{3α}π(r+t)^3ρ - \frac{2}{3α}πr^2tϕ$, ($g$ gets cancelled). However, this is not the correct answer so I'm not sure if there is something wrong with my logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The volume displaced by the "outer ring" of the bowl, i.e. the non-hollow part, would be $\frac{2}{3}πr^2tϕ$. Therefore, the total volume of water displaced by the bowl would be the difference between these, i.e. $\frac{2}{3}π(r+t)^3ρ - \frac{2}{3}πr^2tϕ$.

You're over-complicating things here. When the bowl is floating, there's no fluid inside it, so it displaces the same amount of fluid whether it's solid or hollow.

The critical point happens when the fluid just reaches the rim of the bowl. So the fluid displaced has a solid hemispherical shape. You just need to find how much this volume of fluid weighs, and then how much sand needs to be added to the bowl to give it (bowl + sand) the same weight.

Answer (score 0):

The bowl will sink when the mass of bowl + sand equals the mass of the flid  displace by the hemisphere. So we have

$$\frac{2}{3}\pi\phi(r^3 - (r^3-t^3)) + aT = \frac{2}{3}\pi\rho r^3 \tag{1}$$

Solve for T.